# How To Execute A Split String As Arguments To Clojure.shell/sh

Tags: clojure

I have a command like:

```clj
(clojure.java.shell/sh "curl" "https://somesite.com" "-F" "file=@somefile.txt")
```

and I want to create a function that will run standard shell commands I supply... something like this:

```clj
(defn run-shell-command [command]
  (clojure.java.shell/sh (clojure.string/split command #" ")))
```

so that I could call it like this:

```clj
(run-shell-command "curl https://somesite.com -F file=@somefile.txt")
```

but this throws:

```clj
Unhandled java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
   No value supplied for key: ["curl" "https://somesite.com" "-F" "file=@somefile.txt"]
```

How do I make this work?

(of course, open to better ideas for how to do this)

Comment: Splitting on whitespace is what Groovy does.  And there are questions about it, why it does not work, every day on SO.  Never split commands on whitespace - it works only for every simple cases. Use the "sh -c" approach as suggested.

Comment: Ah, ok... I didn't know that. I haven't gotten the sh -c to work yet, per my comment on the other reply that suggests it, but once I do I'll get it right. That said, I'm happy to have a function that apparently will run arbitrary shell commands from text (useful for copying commands from the interwebs). This seems much easier than converting these commands into, say, clj-http. But is this an anti-pattern of its own, in production say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a common one amongst beginner lispers: If we have a function accepting arguments, how can we **apply** the function on a list of these arguments?

```clj
(defn f [a b c] (+ a b c))

(def args [1 2 3])
```

The answer is, as hinted above, the **[apply](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply)** method. The method applies a function to a list of arguments. So in the example above:

```clj
(= (f 1 2 3)
   (apply f args))
```

i.e

```
(defn run-shell-command [command]
  (apply clojure.java.shell/sh (clojure.string/split command #" ")))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the underlying command processor to process the string.  E.g. using bash:

```clj
(clojure.java.shell/sh "bash" "-c" command)
```

...wrap it in a function and hide the command processor if you wish:

```
(defn run-shell-command [command]
  (clojure.java.shell/sh "bash" "-c" command))
```

then you can use any bash shell commands.  E.g.

```clj
(run-shell-command "for i in $(ls); do echo $i; done")
```